# Urls file in django application

Tags: django, forms

I am working with Django,have a type error TypeError: path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' but my urls.py file reads

```
from . import views 
from importlib.resources import path
from unicodedata import name

urlpatterns=[ 
    path('register_user/ ', views.register, name='user'),
    path('register/', views.registering_patient, name='register_patient')
]
```

Comment: You have to import **`path`** from **Django**: `from django.urls import path`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example